# Unable to use AMQP protocol with network of brokers

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp

Am trying to use AMQP instead of Openwire for network broker connection but it doesn't work for me. The broker A connects with broker B and C in duplex mode.

**Broker A configuration:**

```
<beans 
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
                  http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

                  
                  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
                        <property name="locations">
                          <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
                        </property>
                  </bean>

                  

                  <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="broker-A" networkConnectorStartAsync="true" 
                                  dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="60000" persistent="false">

                        <managementContext>
                          <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
                        </managementContext>

                        <destinationPolicy>
                          <policyMap>
                                <policyEntries>
                                  <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" gcInactiveDestinations="true" 
                                                           inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="300000" optimizedDispatch="true" useCache="false"/> 
                                  <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false" optimizedDispatch="true"/> 
                                </policyEntries>
                          </policyMap>
                        </destinationPolicy>

                        <networkConnectors>

                          <networkConnector 
                                          name="broker-B-topics" 
                                          uri="static:(tcp://broker-B:61616)" 
                                          duplex="true" 
                                          decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" 
                                          dynamicOnly="true">
                                <excludedDestinations>
                                  <queue physicalName=">"/> 
                                </excludedDestinations>
                                <dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                                  <topic physicalName="ActiveMQ.>"/> 
                                  <topic physicalName="testing.>"/> 
                                </dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                          </networkConnector>

                          <networkConnector 
                                          name="broker-B-queues" 
                                          uri="static:(tcp://broker-B:61616)" 
                                          duplex="true" 
                                          decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" 
                                          dynamicOnly="true" 
                                          conduitSubscriptions="false">
                                <excludedDestinations>
                                  <topic physicalName=">"/> 
                                </excludedDestinations>
                                <dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                                  <queue physicalName="testing.>"/> 
                                </dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                          </networkConnector>

                          <networkConnector 
                                          name="broker-C-topics" 
                                          uri="static:(tcp://broker-C:61616)" 
                                          duplex="true" 
                                          decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" 
                                          dynamicOnly="true">
                                <excludedDestinations>
                                  <queue physicalName=">"/> 
                                </excludedDestinations>
                                <dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                                  <topic physicalName="ActiveMQ.>"/> 
                                  <topic physicalName="testing.>"/> 
                                </dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                          </networkConnector>

                          <networkConnector 
                                          name="broker-C-queues" 
                                          uri="static:(tcp://broker-C:61616)" 
                                          duplex="true" 
                                          decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true" 
                                          dynamicOnly="true" 
                                          conduitSubscriptions="false">
                                <excludedDestinations>
                                  <topic physicalName=">"/> 
                                </excludedDestinations>
                                <dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                                  <queue physicalName="testing.>"/> 
                                </dynamicallyIncludedDestinations>
                          </networkConnector>

                        </networkConnectors>

                        <systemUsage>
                          <systemUsage>
                                <memoryUsage>
                                  <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70"/>
                                </memoryUsage>
                                <storeUsage>
                                  <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                                </storeUsage>
                                <tempUsage>
                                  <tempUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                                </tempUsage>
                          </systemUsage>
                        </systemUsage>

                        <transportConnectors>
                          <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
                          <transportConnector name="stomp+nio" uri="stomp+nio://0.0.0.0:61613"/>
                        </transportConnectors>

                  </broker>

                  <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

                </beans>
```

**Broker B configuration:**

```
<beans 
                                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

                  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
                        <property name="locations">
                          <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
                        </property>
                  </bean>

                  <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery" 
                                lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" 
                                init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
                  </bean>

                  <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="broker-B" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" 
                                  networkConnectorStartAsync="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="60000" persistent="false">


                        <destinationPolicy>
                          <policyMap>
                                <policyEntries>
                                  <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" gcInactiveDestinations="true" 
                                                           inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="300000" optimizedDispatch="true" useCache="false"/> 
                                  <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false" optimizedDispatch="true"/> 
                                </policyEntries>
                          </policyMap>
                        </destinationPolicy>

                        <plugins>
                          <timeStampingBrokerPlugin ttlCeiling="0" zeroExpirationOverride="0" futureOnly="true"/>
                        </plugins>

                        <managementContext>
                          <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
                        </managementContext>

                        <systemUsage>
                          <systemUsage>
                                <memoryUsage>
                                  <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70"/>
                                </memoryUsage>
                                <storeUsage>
                                  <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                                </storeUsage>
                                <tempUsage>
                                  <tempUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                                </tempUsage>
                          </systemUsage>
                        </systemUsage>

                        <transportConnectors>
                          <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
                          <transportConnector name="stomp+nio" uri="stomp+nio://0.0.0.0:61615"/>
                        </transportConnectors>
                  </broker>

                </beans>
```

**Broker C configuration:**

```
<beans 
                                xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

                  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
                        <property name="locations">
                          <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
                        </property>
                  </bean>

                  <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery" 
                                lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" 
                                init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
                  </bean>

                  <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="broker-C" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" 
                                  networkConnectorStartAsync="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="60000" persistent="false">


                        <destinationPolicy>
                          <policyMap>
                                <policyEntries>
                                  <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" gcInactiveDestinations="true" 
                                                           inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="300000" optimizedDispatch="true" useCache="false"/> 
                                  <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false" optimizedDispatch="true"/> 
                                </policyEntries>
                          </policyMap>
                        </destinationPolicy>

                        <plugins>
                          <timeStampingBrokerPlugin ttlCeiling="0" zeroExpirationOverride="0" futureOnly="true"/>
                        </plugins>

                        <managementContext>
                          <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
                        </managementContext>

                        <systemUsage>
                          <systemUsage>
                                <memoryUsage>
                                  <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70"/>
                                </memoryUsage>
                                <storeUsage>
                                  <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                                </storeUsage>
                                <tempUsage>
                                  <tempUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                                </tempUsage>
                          </systemUsage>
                        </systemUsage>

                        <transportConnectors>
                          <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
                          <transportConnector name="stomp+nio" uri="stomp+nio://0.0.0.0:61615"/>
                        </transportConnectors>
                  </broker>

                </beans>
```

**Error what am getting in broker-A:**

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  INFO | error with pending remote brokerInfo on: tcp://broker-B/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61616@14953 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 | java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 80 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.looseUnmarshalNestedObject(OpenWireFormat.java:471)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v12.BaseDataStreamMarshaller.looseUnmarsalCachedObject(BaseDataStreamMarshaller.java:487)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v12.ConnectionInfoMarshaller.looseUnmarshal(ConnectionInfoMarshaller.java:154)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.doUnmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:367)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:278)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  INFO | error with pending remote brokerInfo on: tcp://broker-B/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61616@14954 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 | java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 80 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.looseUnmarshalNestedObject(OpenWireFormat.java:471)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v12.BaseDataStreamMarshaller.looseUnmarsalCachedObject(BaseDataStreamMarshaller.java:487)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.v12.ConnectionInfoMarshaller.looseUnmarshal(ConnectionInfoMarshaller.java:154)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.doUnmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:367)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:278)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  WARN | Network connection between vm://broker-A#0 and tcp://broker-B/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61616@14953 shutdown due to a remote error: {} 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 | java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$FutureBrokerInfo.get(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:1828)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.collectBrokerInfos(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:388)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.access$500(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:113)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$5.run(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:366)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  INFO | Network Connector DiscoveryNetworkConnector:broker-C-topics:BrokerService[broker-A] started 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  WARN | Network connection between vm://broker-A#6 and tcp://broker-B/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61616@14954 shutdown due to a remote error: {} 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 | java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$FutureBrokerInfo.get(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:1828)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.collectBrokerInfos(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:388)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.access$500(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:113)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$5.run(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:366)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  INFO | Network Connector DiscoveryNetworkConnector:broker-C-queues:BrokerService[broker-A] started 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  INFO | broker-A bridge to Unknown stopped 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |  INFO | broker-A bridge to Unknown stopped 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.collectBrokerInfos(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:388)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.access$500(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:113)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$5.run(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:366)[activemq-broker-5.15.2.jar:5.15.2] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_91] 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2018/01/18 22:25:45 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91]
```

Not sure why its not connecting properly. Based on another thread http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-configure-Network-of-brokers-successfully-with-AMQP-td4689623.html need configure Openwire protocol's only for Network connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, you need to use an OpenWire based connection for the network connection between brokers.  ActiveMQ supports AMQP clients but for networks you must use the ActiveMQ OpenWire connections, no other network connections are supported.